# Using Jenkins for .Net and J2EE project

Tags: .net, jenkins, msbuild, packaging, msdeploy

I wonder if anyone could help me with some questions on Jenkins. We are using Jenkins for both .Net front-end and J2EE backend projects.

- When using Jenkins to build a .Net project, what would be the step to package the whole project with all the dependencies after build for deployment? I did all the setup with Nuget to grab dependencies and the build is success but I'm still confused about packaging. I'm not sure if I should use "Archive the artifacts" in Add Post Build step or should I use Command Line Arguments under MSBuild. From my understanding, by using "Archive the artifacts" in Add Post Build step we can archive the whole package as a zip file for .Net project or .war/.jar file for Java project. If this is the case, what should I put in "Files to archive" field?
- On the other hand, when using MSBuild I put in these lines under Command Line Arguments:

  /p:Configuration=Release 
  /p:DeployTarget=Package 
  /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True 
  /p:DeployIisAppPath=C:\Project
  /p:PackageLocation=C:\Project\SolutionFile.zip
  /p:IntermediateOutputPath=C:\Project\Temp

When looking at the output, it gives me a PackageTmp folder with contents that I want for the project. However, outside of PackageTmp folder is a Package folder with .cmd, .txt, and two of .xml files. May I ask if these files are used for deployment with MSDeploy.exe? Beside that, outside of Package folder is another folder with lot of .dll, .pdb, and .cache files. May I ask what are these files for and do I need them? The MSBuild also creates a TransformWebConfig folder, I don't know what is this folder for. I come from Java background and I'm not familiar with .Net stack. I'm also not sure if the Command Line Arguments I used for MSBuild are correct.

On the other hand, we use NetBean with our Java project. My understanding is NetBean uses Ant to manage the dependencies. Should we switch to Maven to manage dependencies under Jenkins? What would be the Pros/Cons of using Ant or Maven especially under Jenkins? I apologize for asking many questions. I would greatly appreciate if any expert could help me out. Thank you very much.

I would greatly appreciate if any expert could help me out. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, I think you should split the big topic into smaller ones, it's easier to answer one by one without relating to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The "Files to archive" field should be the out folder (contains .exe or .jav) when you build your solution, starting from your workspace.

For .Net projects, it will be something like this "YourMainProject/bin/Release".\

After that, you can find the output folder in your builds folder.

P/S: i don't usually use Jenkins add-in like that, I prefer a more-complex yet much-more-fun powershell to do all that stuff. (We can even continuously deploy to staging)

Comment: Thanks Hiep. I ended up using MSBuild Command Line Arguments to get a package with .zip file and 2 xml files for deployment via MSScript. May I ask for Java project, what should I put in under "Files to archive" in Archive the Artifacts - Post Build Step. It look like I have to point to a .jar or .war file but I don't know which file to point to. I thought that the .jar or .war files will be generate after the Post Build Step but from some tutorials I have been reading, I have to point to the artifact first and I'm confused. I would greatly appreciate if you could help me out. Thanks.